# Social Context in Ads w/ Redirects

Tags: ads, facebook-ads-api

I'm trying to apply the "Social Context in Ads w/ Redirects" to our creative editor with no luck.
Creating a type 1 creative using a URL redirecting to my Facebook page and setting the "follow_redirect" flag to 1. 
The creative is created successfully but there is no related_fan_page.

Wondering if I'm doing something wrong or maybe my APP is not
approved yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FB drops related_fan_page property if they don't find related fan page in their side.

Use https://graph.facebook.com/search?type=adobjectbyurl&q=URL&access_token=XXX to check which object maps to your URL, and check if you are admin of this object using https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/connectionobjects/.